# SQL | Cumulative Cost with multiple grouping and criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have tried many variations of this SQL statement after much research on this site as well as others, but I'm missing something

My data table looks like:

```
.....Date.....Boolean...Group....Imp......Cost
....1/1/11.....TRUE.........A........High.......$100
....1/1/11.....FALSE........A........Med........$150
....1/1/11.....TRUE.........B........High.......$200
....2/1/11.....TRUE.........B........Low........$300
```

For each month, I want the cumulative cost grouped by "Group" and "Imp."  Here is my SQL query right now, but the cumulative sums (on my much larger data set) are WAAAYYY off.

```
SELECT t1.Date,
       t1.Group,
       t1.Imp,
       Sum(t2.Cost) AS RunTotal
FROM datatable t1
INNER JOIN datatable t2 ON t1.Date >= t2.Date
WHERE t1.Boolean=TRUE
GROUP BY t1.Date,
         t1.Group,
         t1.Imp
```

Note that I can't use cross join since I'm using MS Access.  Any ideas where the error is?

Comment: what does "WAAAYYY off." mean?

Comment: The cumulative totals are 10x-100x (approximately) more than they should be.  I'm trying to find a common factor to help debug, but haven't been able to calculate.

Comment: That's because of the join condition on t1.Date >= t2.Date which has the effect of a restricted  CROSS JOIN...

Comment: What would be an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using the Join at all? This is the query I used, and it seems to work correctly.

```
SELECT [Date], [Group], Img, SUM(Cost) AS RunTotal
FROM datatable WHERE [Boolean] = True
GROUP BY [Date], [Group], Img
```

Comment: This does not provide a running total (at least when I try it out).  Each month just include the sum of previous months.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your running total to be per group and per imp, you need to include that in your join as well:

```
Select t1.Date, t1.Group, t1.Imp, Sum(t2.Cost) as RunTotal
From datatable t1 
Inner Join datatable t2 on t1.Group = t2.Group and t1.Imp = t2.Imp and t1.Date >= t2.Date
WHERE t1.Boolean=TRUE
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.Group, t1.Imp
```

Right now, you are joining with all records where t1.Date >= t2.Date, so that includes records for non-matching group/imp. Just run the following:

```
Select t1.Date, t1.Group, t1.Imp, t2.Date, t2.Group, t2.Imp, t2.Cost
From datatable t1 
Inner Join datatable t2 on t1.Date >= t2.Date
WHERE t1.Boolean=TRUE
```

You should see t2.Cost records you do not want in your sum.